# How to I retrieve the fields from a row in MySql query?

Tags: php, mysql, printing, split

I am trying to retrieve single fields from a row which was retrieved from a MySql database in PHP.

```
$query_string = $query_string = "select * from products where product_id = $product_id";
$result = mysql_query($query_string);
```

and

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

will return a row of a Database with five fields, say A, B, C, D, E.

I want to print out a table on the webpage which will then look like this:

```
field1: A
field2: B
field3: C
field4: D
field5: E
```

how do I split the fields from a row?

Comment: `$row` contains `A, B, C, D, E` means `$row[0] = A`, `$row[1] = B`, ... it should be the ideal case. So, I guess, you just access the values by array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example, you may try this

```
$query_string = "select * from products where product_id = $product_id";
$result = mysql_query($query_string);
if( $result )
{
    $i = 0;
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
    {
        echo $row[$i] . "<br />";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the table column names are `field` and `value`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['field'] . ": " . $row['value'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "field" . ($count+1) . ":" . $row[$count++];

}
```